# .htaccess URL rewriting search id

Tags: .htaccess, url

Simple question, but I cannot seem to find the write tutorial to rewrite my URL.

I am wanting to change

```
www.example.com/search.php?tag=notice
```

To...

```
www.example.com/search/notice
```

How am  I able to achieve this with htaccess URL rewriting?

[This seems like a good tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html) but I cannot follow it to meet my needs.

Comment: what exactly can't you follow?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ /search.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

**Explanation**: removes `search.php` as the file and turns it into a prefix, then it takes what's set by `$_GET['tag']`'s and sets it to the new rewritten url. Using a regex rule you can make `([^/]*)` set to `$1` I'm basically removing search.php from the URL and making it a prefix in the new URL rule.

To add more just simply add more to the Rewrite rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?tag=$1&blah=$2 [L]`
```

Which would look like `example.com/search/SearchingFor/Type` type being a `_GET['type']`. in PHP

Hope this helps, and good luck!